# Jsoup returns 404 error

Tags: java, servlets, jsoup

jsoup-1.8.1

> try {
>               Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
>               return document.getElementsByTag("title").text();
>           } catch (Exception e) {
>               System.out.println(e);
>               return null;
>           }
>
> org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B4

decoded url is here http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/りんご

When I run it in Main function in Local, it runs as I expect.
But If I execute it in Servlet, It returns 404 error.
Non encoded url can be executed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia doesn't allow bots for crawling add `useragent` and `referrer`

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
      .referrer("http://www.google.com")
      .get();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:) If I add above options, That doesn't return a 404 error, but That still has problem.
document.getElementsByTag("title").text() is always Only "Wikipedia"

Comment: what are you trying get?

Comment: In this case, `document.getElementsByTag("title")` should return `<title>リンゴ - Wikipedia</title>` but it returns `<title>Wikipedia</title>`